# Proxy base URL changed - Origin does not correspond to request

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, proxy, iis

I have geoserver 2.21 running under tomcat 9. In IIS I use a url rewrite to redirect all requests from mydomain.com to my local server using an inbound rule. When requesting https://mydomain.com/geoserver/wms. In Qgis i noticed it couldn´t find my layers although the Getmap -requets from https://mydomain.com/geoserver/wms worked fine in open layers and eg. a browser.
Therefore I figured I should set the global proxy base url in geoserver to mydomain.com/geoserver. Now I am only able to log in to geoserver gui and as soon as I try to edit stuff from the gui I get:

[image]

I tried:

- remove the proxy base url which I added but since I can't edit it is not possible. Also tried uncomment and remove this in "tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml" file on the server but this dont seem to kick in (did restart tomcat).
- Adding this to geoserver "tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml":

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST</param-name>
  <param-value>example.com,example.com:8080</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have a CORS-filter set on the tomcat web.xml not the geoserver web.xml, if that matters.

Any ideas what I can do to solve this?

**EDIT:** My proxy set up in IIS is almost identical the steps in described here:

[IIS proxy base url link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/897aa595-7000-4194-802c-ec6d47745b15/step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-iis-arr-with-url-rewrite-for-geoserver?forum=iissetup)

However it differs in two points:

- I used mydomain.com/geoserver in the geoserver global proxy base URL setting. Should I instead use localhost:8080/geoserver? mydomain.com is also set in as my IIS binding.
- The reverse proxy filter seem to be missing in my "web.xml". Should this be added and set to true?

When I choose to go directly to localhost:8080/geoserver/web- as soon as I log in I get redirected to mydomain.com/geoserver/web...and therefore the same issues appear I guess.

Comment: did you change `example.com` to `mydomain.com`?

Comment: Yes, I did.. I did not include /geoserver though but I guess that is not needed? Would it be possible to replace/edit the  global.xml in the geoserver install dir or will this cause more issues? I see several global.tmp without my proxy base edits, saved under the global.xml

Comment: can you add details of how you are proxying to tomcat? Does it work if you go to port 8080?

Comment: @IanTurton, provided some additional details in the question.