# Is it safe to remove global.xml from geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, proxy, iis

After editing proxy base url in global settings of my Geoserver 2.21 I've run into issues where I can't edit anything after logging in to Geoserver gui. I suspect the global.xml is corrupted and  wonder if replacing/deleting it would be a possible way forward to again be able access the gui for edits. I've read (can't find the link now) that removing the global.xml will automatically produce a new "clean" one. Could anyone confirm this is true?

This would possibly solve the symptoms of my problem. The root cause is still not solved but problem is covered here: [Proxy base URL changed - Origin does not correspond to request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/445993/70080)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest simply editing `global.xml` and remove the "proxy base URL" related elements instead.

Comment: After setting proxy base url to     ”nothing” in global.xml geoserver now allow my edits in gui again. Thanks